# Can someone tell me what this thing is?

Tags: capacitor, identification

[image]

[**More images are here:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq46F.jpg)

Numbers are:

500B - On the back

6800
+5%
80 - on the front

Comment: It looks like an old soviet film capacitor

Comment: The "6800" marking would support that theory, although I've never seen any capacitor built like that before.

Comment: Better focus would be much more useful - if camera will not focus at that distance hold it furthe away - small and shrp is better than large and fuzzy. More light almost always helps.

Comment: Sorry i was taking a picture with my phone witch has a pretty bad camera

Comment: Russell's advice works for bad cameras, too :)

Answer (score 3):

It is soviet silver mica capacitor. Old but still good quality. 500B (read as 500V) is the maximum voltage. 6800 is 6800pF or 6.8nF. 5% is the capacitance tolerance.

Comment: thanks, found it in some old circuit board, there is a lot more of them